# Saddle-node-equilibrium for $\mu=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider
$$
u_t=\cos(u)+\mu, u\in S^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}.
$$
for some parameter $\mu$.

For $\mu=1$, the equilibria are
$$
u=k\pi.
$$
Consider, for example $u=\pi$. Is this stable or unstable?

If I linearize the equation around $u=\pi$, I get
$$
u_t=-\sin(\pi)(u-\pi)=0
$$
so the eigenvalues of the linearization are $\lambda_{1,2}=0$.

So this seems to be a non-hyperbolic eigenvalue.

For $\lvert \mu\rvert<1$ there is one stable and one unstable equilibrium and for $\lvert\mu\rvert>1$ there is no equilibrium.

So is the equilibrium for $\mu=1$ a saddle-node equilibrium or how is this called?

Comment: saddle-node is correct.

Comment: A small correction:  For $\mu = 1$, the *eigenvalue* of the linearization at $u = \pi$ *is* $\lambda_1 = 0$.